# How to find the perimeter of objects in a binary image in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

I'm using c# and aforge.net to find the perimeter of objects in following image.
[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6YRl.jpg)

### what I've done till now  is ...

1. made image binary.
2. found the blobs.
3. Extracted image for each blob.
4. used MoravecCornersDetector class to find edge points.

When I draw Points, the result is like following image.
[Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdTar.jpg)

### Now my problem is ...

Now my problem is sorting these points to make a polygon and sum the distance between them to find perimeter.
Would you mind tell me How can I do this?
Do you know any better way to find perimeter?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curImage = new Bitmap(@"1.jpg");

        extractBlob(ThresholdImage(curImage));
    }

    Bitmap ThresholdImage(Bitmap image)
    {
        Bitmap result;
        using (Bitmap aa = image)
        {
            // create grayscale filter (BT709)
            Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
            // apply the filter
            Bitmap grayImage = filter.Apply(aa);

            // create filter
            Threshold filter2 = new Threshold(200);
            // apply the filter
            filter2.ApplyInPlace(grayImage);
            result = new Bitmap(grayImage);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    void extractBlob(Bitmap image)
    {
        BlobCounterBase bc = new BlobCounter();
        bc.FilterBlobs = true;
        bc.MinHeight = 5;
        bc.MinWidth = 5;

        bc.ProcessImage(image);
        Blob[] blobs = bc.GetObjectsInformation();
        for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
        {
            bc.ExtractBlobsImage(image, blobs[i], true);
            Bitmap copy = blobs[i].Image.ToManagedImage();
            Edge(copy);
            // ------> Draw Edge(copy)
        }
        
    }

    List<PointF> Edge(Bitmap image)
    {
        // create corner detector's instance
        MoravecCornersDetector mcd = new MoravecCornersDetector();

        // process image searching for corners
        List<IntPoint> corners = mcd.ProcessImage(image);

        List<PointF> eachObject = new List<PointF>();

        foreach (var item in corners)
        {
            PointF p = new PointF(item.X, item.Y);
            eachObject.Add(p);
        }
        return eachObject;
    }
```

Comment: This is unlikely to work out, since perimeter is extremely sensitive to noise / irregularity.

Comment: For the question you asked -- if the shapes were convex, you could use the centroid as an origin location, and sort the points by angle.  But the shapes aren't convex, this may fail.